# How to resize my bitmap as 16*16 size or 32*32

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, reduce

I want to resize my bitmap image to icon size.I have written one function for that.But its zoomed out.But i want to make the image width and height also smaller.its not get decremented after a certain width and height.How can i zoom it down to an icon size ?

Here is my function..

```
            private Bitmap getImagemap(File f){
        try {
            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=80;

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale=1;
            while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale*=2;

            //Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be helpful and easy,

```
   Bitmap bmp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourbitmap, 32, 32, false);
```

Comment: let me see..i think it wont work..however i can call it after my function call..ok let me see

Comment: yeah..good idea.Thanks.it got worked only after my function call

Comment: accept answers which solves your problem, so that users can see which is the answer of  question or which answer solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The scale option is for scaling.

For what you are trying to do, you need to use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` (parameters self-explanatory)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this is working like charm**

```
private String decodeFile(String path,int DESIREDWIDTH,int DESIREDHEIGHT) {
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        try {
            // Part 1: Decode image
            Bitmap unscaledBitmap = ScalingUtilities.decodeFile(path, DESIREDWIDTH, DESIREDHEIGHT, ScalingLogic.FIT);

            if (!(unscaledBitmap.getWidth() <= DESIREDWIDTH && unscaledBitmap.getHeight() <= DESIREDHEIGHT)) {
                // Part 2: Scale image
                scaledBitmap = ScalingUtilities.createScaledBitmap(unscaledBitmap, DESIREDWIDTH, DESIREDHEIGHT, ScalingLogic.FIT);
            } else {
                unscaledBitmap.recycle();
            }
            if(scaledBitmap!=null){
                return  scaledBitmap;
            }else{
                return unscaledBitmap;
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }



    }
```

**ScalingUtilities.java**

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;

/**
 * Class containing static utility methods for bitmap decoding and scaling
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class ScalingUtilities {

    /**
     * Utility function for decoding an image resource. The decoded bitmap will
     * be optimized for further scaling to the requested destination dimensions
     * and scaling logic.
     *
     * @param res The resources object containing the image data
     * @param resId The resource id of the image data
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Decoded bitmap
     */
    public static Bitmap decodeResource(Resources res, int resId, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, dstWidth,
                dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        return unscaledBitmap;
    }
    public static Bitmap decodeFile(String path, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, dstWidth,
                dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        return unscaledBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Utility function for creating a scaled version of an existing bitmap
     *
     * @param unscaledBitmap Bitmap to scale
     * @param dstWidth Wanted width of destination bitmap
     * @param dstHeight Wanted height of destination bitmap
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return New scaled bitmap object
     */
    public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(Bitmap unscaledBitmap, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        Rect srcRect = calculateSrcRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Rect dstRect = calculateDstRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstRect.width(), dstRect.height(),
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(unscaledBitmap, srcRect, dstRect, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        return scaledBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * ScalingLogic defines how scaling should be carried out if source and
     * destination image has different aspect ratio.
     *
     * CROP: Scales the image the minimum amount while making sure that at least
     * one of the two dimensions fit inside the requested destination area.
     * Parts of the source image will be cropped to realize this.
     *
     * FIT: Scales the image the minimum amount while making sure both
     * dimensions fit inside the requested destination area. The resulting
     * destination dimensions might be adjusted to a smaller size than
     * requested.
     */
    public static enum ScalingLogic {
        CROP, FIT
    }

    /**
     * Calculate optimal down-sampling factor given the dimensions of a source
     * image, the dimensions of a destination area and a scaling logic.
     *
     * @param srcWidth Width of source image
     * @param srcHeight Height of source image
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Optimal down scaling sample size for decoding
     */
    public static int calculateSampleSize(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return srcWidth / dstWidth;
            } else {
                return srcHeight / dstHeight;
            }
        } else {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return srcHeight / dstHeight;
            } else {
                return srcWidth / dstWidth;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates source rectangle for scaling bitmap
     *
     * @param srcWidth Width of source image
     * @param srcHeight Height of source image
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Optimal source rectangle
     */
    public static Rect calculateSrcRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.CROP) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                final int srcRectWidth = (int)(srcHeight * dstAspect);
                final int srcRectLeft = (srcWidth - srcRectWidth) / 2;
                return new Rect(srcRectLeft, 0, srcRectLeft + srcRectWidth, srcHeight);
            } else {
                final int srcRectHeight = (int)(srcWidth / dstAspect);
                final int scrRectTop = (int)(srcHeight - srcRectHeight) / 2;
                return new Rect(0, scrRectTop, srcWidth, scrRectTop + srcRectHeight);
            }
        } else {
            return new Rect(0, 0, srcWidth, srcHeight);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates destination rectangle for scaling bitmap
     *
     * @param srcWidth Width of source image
     * @param srcHeight Height of source image
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Optimal destination rectangle
     */
    public static Rect calculateDstRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, (int)(dstWidth / srcAspect));
            } else {
                return new Rect(0, 0, (int)(dstHeight * srcAspect), dstHeight);
            }
        } else {
            return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, dstHeight);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: unscaled bitmap has already recycled. The else part i.e `else{
                return unscaledBitmap;
            }` will throw nullpointer